# Controlling the click event of a button on the save as dialog box

Tags: asp.net, events, dialog, click

How should I control the click event of the save button on the save as dialog box?
I need to update a flag when the save button is clicked.
I'm creating a web application using VB.NET 2.0
Thanks.

Comment: do you want to upload a file?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.  The dialog is part of the browser that you cannot access.